# Invalid left-hand side in assignment in a simple thing I have to do

Tags: javascript

So I get the error Invalid left-hand side on line 12 (where the var declaration is) in assignment for this code:

```
<html>
  <head>Guessing Game</head>
  <body>
    <p>"Hello! Welcome to the Guessing Game of Life or Slavery. Remember to use correct spelling and punctuation!"</p>
    <form id ="q1" action = "">
      "What is the meaning of life the universe and everything?"
      <input type = "text" >
    </form>
    <script>
      var answerOne = function(){
        var theAnswer = "42"
        if("text" == theAnswer){
          prompt("TEST!")
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am just testing this out...what I really want to do is make a webpage where I answer that question and it says "You're right on the webpage

Comment: Seems to be running fine in Chrome.  Which browser are you using?

Comment: That code does not give that error (even if I run the function manually as you provide no way to trigger it in the page)

Comment: Also no _error_ here, but also not the behavior @NoahM seems to want. Do you know about `document.getElementById`? You have to explicitly fetch what is written in an `input`...

Comment: `if("text" == theAnswer)` will always return false. To get the value of the textbox you need to give your `text` input an ID and retrieve it with `document.getElementById('inputid').value`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what u needed? :

```
<script>
function answerOne(){

var theAnswer = "42"
    var answerGiven= document.getElementById('answer').value;
  if(answerGiven == theAnswer){
         //code for correct answer
         alert("correct");
    }
  else {
      //code for incorrect answer
      alert("incorrect");
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>"Hello! Welcome to the Guessing Game of Life or Slavery. Remember to use correct spelling and punctuation!"</p>
<form id ="q1" action = "" onsubmit="answerOne();" >
  "What is the meaning of life the universe and everything?"
  <input type = "text" id="answer">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"  >
 </form>
```

Note : Form Validation is not done and needs to be done in case user enters any invalid values